# Spring MVC: Ambiguous RequestMappings after moving to JavaConfig

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations, ambiguous

After moving from XML setup to a JavaConfig setup many of our RequestMappings have broken and now return ambiguous method errors. Our methods rely on @PathVariable's with regular expressions to determine which to call.  For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/{id:\\d+}/boats"})
public String getBoatsById(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model,
HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {...}

@RequestMapping(value={"/{id}/boats"})
public String getBoatsByName(@PathVariable("id") String id, Model model,
HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {...}
```

This use to work with out issue but using the new JavaConfig setup versus the XML setup it breaks with the ambiguous errors due to the mappings.

The JavaConfig class starts as such:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example", excludeFilters = { @ComponentScan.Filter( Configuration.class ) })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport
```

Would it have anything to do with the XML setup using the AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter versus the JavaConfig class now using the recommended RequestMappingHandlerAdapter?  Is there a setting I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Just browsed the source code, `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` uses a different `RequestMappingInfo` than `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`. The former ignores the pattern/path you have specified when checking for equality while the latter honors it. That's why you are having ambiguous mapping errors. Not sure if it is a bug or not, probably it's good to ask the people at the spring-contrib mailing list.

**EDIT**

Probably it's a good idea to change your mappings. The `{name:reg_exp}` syntax was introduced not to solve ambiguity. Excerpt from the official documentation:

> Sometimes you need more precision in defining URI template variables.
>   Consider the URL "/spring-web/spring-web-3.0.5.jar". How do you break
>   it down into multiple parts?
>
> The @RequestMapping annotation supports the use of regular expressions
>   in URI template variables. The syntax is {varName:regex} where the
>   first part defines the variable name and the second - the regular
>   expression.For example:
>
> ```java
> @RequestMapping("/spring-web/{symbolicName:[a-z-]+}-{version:\d\.\d\.\d}{extension:\.[a-z]+}")
> public void handle(@PathVariable String version, @PathVariable String extension) {
>     // ...
>
>    }
> }
> ```

Your handler methods were ambiguous from the start, you only provided a hackish way to solve the ambiguity.